# Authentication in ASP.NET HttpHandler

Tags: asp.net

I have created a HttpHandler to be used with SWFUpload to upload images to the server.  This upload is done in an administration backend so users need to be authenticated to upload images.

Initially I made the whole administration area deny annonymous users but because of the way SWFUpload appears to work it wouldn't work correctly with Forms authentication and would return a 302 status code.

I had thought it would be possible to make the location of my handler public in Web.config and use context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated in my handler to determine if the user is logged in.

**My problem**: is that `context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` always seems false in the handler after I have logged in.  Does anyone have any thoughts on why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was specific to some code added to Global.asax to fix SWFUpload cookie bug for non-IE browsers.  I had modified the value of the `session_cookie_name` variable in the Application_BeginRequest event handler to be the same name as I had set in Web.config.

Doing this breaks the functionality across all browsers.  The variable value should be left set to its default "ASP.NET_SESSIONID".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need to use [IRequiresSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx):

```
public class CustomGenericHandler : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{
//code
}
```

All your sessions will then be usable in the generic handler.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Seems like it's still coming up false for me.  Maybe I'm doing something odd here?

Comment: You do not need IRequiresSessionState if You are using FormsAuthentication. It is only needed if you access Session directly.

Comment: FormsAuthentication uses sessions as well.
Jason, this is strange as this is what I had to do to make my code work.

Comment: Could it be because the handler is called from the client side in SWFUpload?

Comment: No because I'm calling it from jquery ajax. Can you make sure the user is logged in, I'm just thinking sometimes when developing the sessions get restarted while the developer doesn't notice- so just make sure the user is logged in and then try to run it.

Comment: User is logged in.  But I've discovered that it's my own fault.  Will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using when testing?

Your solution should work in IE but will fail in FireFox since SwfUpload is Flash based and Flash always send IE cookies to the server since you are logging in (and thereby creating a ASP.NET session cookie) in Firefox but SwfUpload send a different set of cookies.

Comment: I'm using IE for debugging and it's still not working there.  I've also added the suggested code to Global.asax as found in the SWFUpload samples.

Comment: Is context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated always false or just during the SwfUpload requests?

Comment: Only during the SWFUpload requests.